# Need help repositioning and resizing widgets with Python Tkinter grid

Tags: python, grid, resize

Hi guys I was wondering if I could get some help on how to resize widgets with .grid on tkinter. I have no clue and I've tried weight= but it doesn't do anything.

I also need help moving the two combo boxes in my code to certain areas. Normally the widgets are layered depending on where they are in the code but it doesn't seem to be the case with the combo boxes. I want the first combo box to be after the first input box and then the second box after the label "To"

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Currency Converter")
root.geometry("365x436")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

QuoteCurrencyConverter = Label(app, font="calibri 24 bold underline", text =     "Currency Converter")
QuoteCurrencyConverter.grid()

InputAmount = Entry(app) 
InputAmount.grid()

ComboBoxVariable = StringVar(root)
ComboBoxVariable.set("AUD")

ComboBox1 = OptionMenu(root, ComboBoxVariable, "AUD", "USD", "YEN", "CAD", "EUR", "GBP")
ComboBox1.grid()

QuoteTo = Label(app, font="calibri 24", text = "To")
QuoteTo.grid()

ComboBoxVariable1 = StringVar(root)
ComboBoxVariable1.set("AUD")

ComboBox2 = OptionMenu(root, ComboBoxVariable1, "AUD", "USD", "YEN", "CAD", "EUR", "GBP")
ComboBox2.grid()

ConvertButton = Button(app, font="calibri 13 bold", text = "Convert")
ConvertButton.grid()

DisplayAmount = Entry(app) #CURRENTLY UNSURE#
DisplayAmount.grid()

ResetButton = Button(app, font="calibri 13 bold", text = "Reset")
ResetButton.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try to use the .pack(side="right", padx=5,pady=5)

You can pack the items in the widget you have created.

side can be right left top bottom, then you can use pady and padx to move them.

Please let me know if this help. Have a nice day.

Comment: It worked, I've tinkered a lot with the files now, thank you!!

Comment: Always welcome :-) you need to play a bit, but you can make some useful interfaces :) Have fun and a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The `tkinter.grid` arranges the widgets in a form of rows and columns. What you said about adding widgets where they appear in the code is incorrect. The `grid` function has 2 optional parameters - `row` and `column`. Perhaps the names are enough to make you understand their use. But let me tell you. Both of them must be positive integers. Now set the row and column accordingly like in Microsoft Excel though both must be integers. Now if you mean to resize them, use the `rowspan` and `columnspan` attributes.

Example:

`frame.grid(row=3, column=4, rowspan=4, columnspan=2)`

Comment: Just tried the row/col etc and everything besides column= stays the same. No matter what number I put for the other 3 it stays the same, and column just moves it out of the centre. There is no change in anything when I put them in, am I meant to fill in everything and not just 1 widget? I'm sure that isn't the problem either.